# Interop problem- - Different C# structure for different OS Architecture

Tags: .net, interop

I have a C++ structure, and I have to interop it from my C# code.

I compile my C# code as a platform agnostic dll, which means that I can use the same C# dll on different platforms ( **32bit or 64bit-- doesn't matter**), whereas I distribute the C++ differently for different platforms.

The problem is that the C++ structure that I must interop seems to work for different C# definition. In 64 bit OS, the following structure works:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct MayDay_CONTEXT
    {
        public System.UInt32  dwIndex;      //previously was int
        public System.UInt32 dwVersion;     //previously was int        
        public System.UInt64 hLock;         //previously was int
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 12)]
        public byte[] reserve;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 56)]
        public byte[] bAtr;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public byte[] bID;
        public uint dwAtrLen;
    }
```

but in 32 bit OS, the following structure works:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct MayDay_CONTEXT
    {
        public int  dwIndex;        //previously was int
        public int dwVersion;       //previously was int        
        public int hLock;           //previously was int
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 12)]
        public byte[] reserve;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 56)]
        public byte[] bAtr;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public byte[] bID;
        public uint dwAtrLen;
    }
```

Is there anyway to set the structure member's type at runtime? I know I need a kind of duck typing to do it, but maybe there is a better solution... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would `IntPtr` (for `hLock`) work? Otherwise, you'll probably have to use #if definitions in your source... - i.e.

```
#if X86
     ..
#else
     ..
#endif
```

and define the `X86` symbol in your 32-bit builds (there isn't anything built in)

Comment: As mentioned, I don't want to compile 2 versions of my C# code, so the #If #endif is not preferred.

Comment: I think you missed the initial suggestion of using an IntPtr (which doesn't require a #if)